# performance of matlab's image processing toolkit

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cbir

I've Heard that Matlab's image processing library is quite slow compared to Java's image processing library..

is that true ??

If thats the case, then will it be feasible to implement applications like **CBIR** Image search engine using Matlab ??

Comment: I imagine the relative speeds of the two libraries will depend greatly on what sort of image processing you are doing. As such, I feel that this question may be too open-ended.

Comment: well, I'm more specific on using filters on image and my major concern is about using Gabor filter on image.

Comment: I have heard it from unreliable sources and I'm not too sure whether its right or wrong.. Hence I'm asking this question to verify whether its true or false...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, Matlab is really good for prototyping.  You can implement algorithms quickly, and you can easily visualize the results.  That is the advantage of using Matlab: fast development, not fast processing.

If you want to implement an actual computer vision or image processing application to be used by real people, I would suggest using C++, at least for the core image processing functions, because speed is a much bigger factor in this case.  Specifically, [openCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) comes to mind.

Comment: This is certainly the approach to use if processing time is of utmost importance. But there are plenty of situations where the potential speed gains of a C++ implementation over a parallelized Matlab version are not worth the investment in terms of development time.

Comment: @Jonas, I agree entirely. But this is always a judgment call, since development time is hard to gauge in advance.  Still, I believe that in most cases, if you are building a production system which does a lot of image processing, you are better off implementing it in C++. If not all of it, then the most compute-intensive parts.